# Computer Modern Serif for both linux and windows

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, amsfonts

There's a high probability that my question was asked before, but I couldn't find a good answer to it, so I'm going to pose the question again, hoping that I will get the accurate answer to my question.

I use both linux and windows with my personal cloud that synchronizes my data on multiple computers. I'm currently writing a 150+ pages scientific document on latex that uses the default latex font. After digging to know the name of that font, I found that the font name is Computer Modern Serif (Is that right?) (I use report class in latex, is that the default font for it?)

Now I have schematics and figures that I made with Inkscape. I need those to be openable in both windows and linux, but, ... I couldn't find the font that would be common between windows and linux. Under linux, the font is called "Serif". Under windows it's called "CMU Serif", of course after manually installing it on windows.

How can I have a single font name for both windows and linux (without manually messing font names) so that I don't have to change the name of the font the whole time? I expect to have a font that has exactly the same name from linux, and then just install it on windows, and voila! No problem anymore in both operating systems.

1- Is that possible?

2- Are the font names I mentioned correct? I really am lost in this.

Please advise.

Comment: although i don't know the answer to your question (which implies "system fonts" for linux and windows), i am rather confused by the name "cmu serif".  the main computer modern text font, as used by tex, is known to tex users as "cmr" (for "computer modern roman", a serif font).  in that system, "cmu" is a different font -- unslanted italic (also a serif font, but with quite a different lettershapes).  but as you want to use the fonts outside of a tex environment, it's possible that different names have been assigned.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I suspected at the beginning of my search that the font name should have something to do with "roman" due to similarity of the latex font with Times New Roman of windows... but after digging a lot, I found only CMU Serif to look like the latex font... This issue gave me headache... and that's why I'm asking also for the font name and whether it's incorrect. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton cm-unicode includes an opentype font with the name CMU Serif Roman. Perhaps that is it?

Comment: Is Latin Modern Roman an option for you? It is very similar to Computer Modern and I think it would be more straightforward to keep track of in terms of names etc. TeX distributions already include opentype versions which you could install as system fonts for both Linux and Windows. In your TeX document, `\usepackage{lmodern}` would select the type1 version of the font and this should match pretty much perfectly. (Whereas I'm not sure whether that will be as easy for CM.)

Comment: @cfr -- you're probably right about the cm-unicode naming.  (but it's rather unfortunate for "old dogs" like me.  i actually *do* have a justifiable use for the unslanted italic, which is a surprise to many people.)  i think your suggestion regarding latin modern is a good alternative.

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest solution be to just install ``cm-unicode`` on your linux system? http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @cfr Actually I do use `\usepackage{lmodern}`, and your solution is good. But the problem now is that the Latin Modern Roman font is called "LM Roman 10" in windows. I couldn't find a font called "Latin Modern Roman" exactly.

Comment: That's because Latin Modern (like Computer Modern) comes in slightly different versions for different sizes of text. You should use the one that is appropriate for the size font you have set. (I don't know Inkscape but I imagine you can select a font size like `12pt` or `8pt`.) You can use `tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd` to figure out which font is used for which point size. Let me know if you'd like an answer explaining this. Roughly, the line `<6.5-7.5> ec-lmr7` would mean that for point sizes between `6.5` and `7.5` you'd use Latin Modern Roman 7, for example.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your response. The slight differences between different sizes is of no interest for me. I could accept size 10 with no problems. But this doesn't solve the problem, in which I can have the same font name in Windows and Linux, does it? Please explain whether it does, or whether there's a next step.

Comment: So you've installed exactly the same opentype font on both the Windows and Linux systems and the name appears differently in Inkscape in the two cases?

Comment: @cfr I have the font "Latin Modern Roman" by default in my linux installation, and it's the font that is used by my latex document. Now I installed it on Windows, and it has a different name. Is the only way to fix this by renaming this font manually?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why that would happen. I would first check that the font you are using in Linux is, in fact, the very same font and not a slightly different one. Check the opentype file is identical to the one you installed on Windows. If it is, I'm not sure - I know nothing about how fonts work on Windows. I don't know why Windows would include the font size. Did you install just the one font or did you also include the other sizes? I wonder if it would make a difference if it new there were several sizes. (Maybe it would group them as in Linux.)

Comment: @cfr I'm using the command you mentioned with lmodern. In Windows, normally font size is not a part of the font. This is the case only for this font... In Windows, it now has the name LM Modern 10, for size 10...

Comment: Isn't the issue having the same font name in Inkscape on both machines? If so, `lmodern` is irrelevant to that problem, isn't it? It may be that Windows does that. (Most fonts don't come with different optical sizes. Some commercial fonts do. But if you are using standard Windows fonts, say, LM is probably the only one you have which has such possibilities.)

Comment: @cfr It just happens by coincidence that I'm using lmodern font... and I'm looking for a simple font that I can copy to my fonts folder in windows and have it for all sizes... I thought it's a simple thing to do, but apparently it isn't...

Comment: I'm lost. I thought you wanted the following (1) labels in your figures (produced in Inkscape) to use text matching that in your document; (2) the same font with the same name in Inkscape on 2 systems. `lmodern` + Latin Modern in opentype format should take care of (1). Installing the same opentype Latin Modern font on both Linux and Windows should take care of (2). But you have not said whether you have installed the same opentype font on both systems. You've just said Latin Modern is installed by default on Linux. But is it the same font file?

Comment: I have the impression that your problem has to do with the type LaTeX font differing in origin TrueType and OpenType. Unless you're using XeTeX or LuaTeX to compile, I assume you do with pdfTeX and LaTeX's default font.

That should not cause any problems because as you have pointed out, there are opentype versions of the Computer Modern family is that you could use with both systems. In that sense I think is more annoying sometimes install them on linux.

Comment: @cfr OK, let's tackle the problem in a different way. Where can I find Latin Modern Roman as opentype font in linux? I looked in the fonts directory in linux but I couldn't find the file responsible for that! I could only find only many files, each with different size and different name! http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/

Comment: @Aradnix My problem is that a font with the name Latin Modern Roman as opentype or truetype doesn't even exist! If it does, please provide me with it in like one file and then problem is solved!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Let me search tomorrow and I'll help you.

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm includes the fonts in opentype format. But whatever font file you installed on Windows, you can install on Linux. That is, you are not worried about what is installed for TeX here. You just need to make sure Inkscape has access to the same font on the two systems. You've got the file you installed on Windows, so install that on Linux.

Comment: @cfr My friend, please try to understand the problem! If you would install those fonts on windows, their name will be LM Roman 10 or something similar. I'm looking for a single font called Latin Modern Roman as a single font and not font size dependent font. I honestly don't know how linux deals with it, but I need 1 file for windows that produces 1 font with 1 name... probably 4 files for the different combination of regular, bold and italtic. But not more!!! Installing this on linux will just complicate the issue even more! The font is available already in linux with the name Latin Modern R.

Comment: There is no such font. Latin Modern uses optical font sizes. That is part of its design. There is no single file which corresponds to 'Latin Modern Roman' simpliciter. I suspect that you do not have the same font files installed on the two systems. That is very likely to create problems. You haven't told us what Linux is using system-wide so it isn't possible to confirm this. But that's my suspicion.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but rather a workaround that might be appropriate. When creating figures in Inkscape, there is an option to export to pdf with your inkscape text substituted for LaTeX code, to be positioned in the same place in the figure. The tutorial found [here](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/inkscape-images-with-latex-fonts/) should show you what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Well, sorry, but I think you're wanting to do this bigger than it is. You can use a font that you want to `LaTeX`. There is a good catalog of *native* fonts and you can always use `ttf` and `otf` fonts using `XeLaTeX` as you know.

On the other hand, [Computer Modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) is a very good source, ideal for working with math, but not the only one. You say you're using Latin Modern Roman that it's [another project](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern).

I think there is a confusion at this point. According to this [article in the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) and the references related, you can get the font family [from here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/) in open Type format, suitable for use with `Inkscape` and easy to install in Windows (leave aside for a moment to gnu/linux to keep things simple).

Also @cfr sent you the path for download the Latin Modern fonts in open type. In my own experience isn't hard to install this kind of fonts. I would download all the files from the directory for get all the weights and variations of the font available.

This would be enough for satisfy the point 1 of your question.

To answer the second point, you need to know something about fonts to begin the fact that not always the family name is synonymous with guarantee. Often fonts with the same name but produced by different manufacturers differ in details to each other. There is almost always subtle differences in strokes in the number of glyphs and sometimes includes encoding of some characters. The more delicate is the kerning, which can produce ugly spaces in `LaTeX`.

In that sense, my suggestion is to try the versions stored on CTAN, which although Open Type, can be used either to `LaTeX`.

The latest idea or option, is to try `XeLaTeX` and another font. However the problem is that commercial fonts have a very small set of mathematical symbols. There are *pi* fonts that complement but are not very extensive, and are not always combine well with the main font.

To me, for example, I like to use Palatino by Hermann Zapf, so in `LaTeX` I can use mathpazo (extended version of Palatino for mathematics in `LaTeX`), thus I can happily use Palatino in Inkscape, Illustrator or whatever.This works great if you don't require special symbols to create diagrams. I don't know if it's your case, but I hope this helps.